# Mysql v5.1.50 retuns string instead of decimal on DIFFERENT computers

Tags: mysql, sum

I have two PC's both of them with Win2008 R2 set it up exactly the same. 
On one PC the `sum(FIELD_NAME)` returns a decimal number (CORRECTY) on the other
the same `sum(FIELD_NAME)` returns the same number as STRING !!!

I have set the System_Time_Zone to be the same on both PC (GTB Standard Time) but the problem still exist. I had uninstall and install back again MySQL on the second PC but still no luck.
I had try tzutil (O/S command) and set the time zone to the above desired but still have the same problem.

With `show variables like "%time_zone%"` the correct pc shows

```
system_time_zone : GTB Standard Time
time_zone : System
```

the "wrong" pc shows

```
system_time_zone : AN EMPTY SPACE
time_zone : System
```

my final solution is to reinstal Windows again but.... :o((((

any suggestions ?????

Comment: SO why cant you cast that sum as a number in your query?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you confirm the version of the MySQL Connector you are using (not clear whether you are using the Connector/ODBC, Connector/Net or Connector/J.

What MySQL returns is interpreted/translated by the Connector. I think the issue is likely a differnce in the connector being used, or the verison of the connector, or possibly just a difference in the configuration of the Connector (for example, the DFLT_BIGINT_BIND_STR parameter in Connector/ODBC.)

(Less likely, the behavior you observe could be due to a difference in the characterset encodings.)

The details for configuration, debugging and tracing are different for each Connector.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/index-connectors.html